# What is "homegrown nana"

Tags: dialogue, from-paris-with-love

In *From Paris with Love* there is a scene where Charlie Wax gets served mint tea by an old man. He then asks how he make his own tea just as good and the old man replies something like "You can't, it is homegrown nana.". I am curious what "nana" is in the sentence above, is it some kind of mint, or is he referring to something else?

Comment: He asks "How can I get it?", I think - like saying where to buy this stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting directly [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maghrebi_mint_tea), Nana is the type of mint typically used in mint tea in the Greater Maghreb region.

> The cultivar spearmint (Mentha spicata) Nana, possesses a clear,
>   pungent, but mild aroma, and is the mint that is traditionally used in
>   Maghrebi mint tea. Other hybrids and cultivars of Mentha, including
>   Yerba buena, are occasionally used as substitutes for Nana mint.

Comment: Seems I should have googled for "nana" connected to mint, as opposed to connected to the movie. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @eirikdaude - It's only seems obvious *after* you've seen it :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Nana" is the arabic word for mint.

Comment: yes it is true.

Comment: If you could extrapolate on this more it would probably be a good answer.  As it currently is, it's not that great.